# Placeholder text not showing in textarea when generated with javascript (tags on the same line)

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, placeholder

The placeholder text is not showing in my text area that I created with javascript until I click into the box.

```
var input = document.createElement("textarea");
input.rows = "2";
input.placeholder = placeholder;
```

I've read a lot of the same questions about this and it is usually because the textarea tags are on different lines however, my tags are generated by javascript and when I look at the source the tags are on the same line and there appears to be nothing between the tags.  The HTM generated is:

```
<textarea placeholder="Enter here" rows="2"></textarea>
```

Comment: What is the value of `placeholder` when `input.placeholder = placeholder;` runs?

Comment: It's a variable passed into the function but is "Enter here"

Comment: can you post the whole function and a snippet of code if you have it?

Comment: The HTML generated looks OK. Show a complete example that reproduces the issue.